# Turn off ggvis output if radiobutton is selected

Tags: r, ggvis, shiny

I have a radio button that I would like to use in my ui.R file to turn on and off the ggvis plot. When the radio button is set to on, I will display the ggvis plot. When it is turned off, I would like to show a table output instead. I have the following code.

```
if(input$check==on){
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")}
```

I get the following error.

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
```

I am wondering how I could check whether input$check(the radio is turned on) then decide to show ggvis, otherwise display a table.

Answer (score 1):

Use `conditionalPanel`. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html

Here is an example that is in one of my `ui.R` files:

```
sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("compare", "Select By Date or Price",
                     c("Previous Date", "Price Change"), selected = "Previous Date"),
        br(),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.compare == 'Previous Date'",
          uiOutput("date_selected")
          ),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.compare == 'Price Change'",
          numericInput("price_change", "Enter Price Change %", 0, -100, 100)
          )
        )
```

Just change the `output`.